# Cannot get Angular/Restangular form data in Go

Tags: angularjs, go, restangular, gorilla

I have a Go rest service that works fine, I can get form data using a Chrome REST plugin.
I need to get form data from my Angular app to the service, and so far I cannot figure it out.

My Angular code:

```
<form name="myForm">
<div class="control-group" ng-class="{error: myForm.name.$invalid}">
    <label>Drug Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="drugName" ng-model="drug.name" required>
      <span ng-show="myForm.drugName.$error" class="help-inline">
                                                    Required</span>
</div>
<a href="#/" class="btn">Cancel</a>
<button ng-click="save()" ng-disabled="isClean() || myForm.$invalid"
                                        class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
<button ng-click="destroy()" ng-show="project._id"
                                        class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
</form>
```

My app.js CreateCtrl, I set `RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('/rest/v1');`:

```
function CreateCtrl($scope, $location, Restangular) {
$scope.save = function() {
    Restangular.all('drugs/').post($scope.drug).then(function(project) {
        $location.path('/list');
    });
}
}
```

In my Go code, I am using gorilla, and here are the pertinent parts:

```
http.Handle("/rest/v1/drugs/", drugs.MakeMuxer("/rest/v1/drugs/"));
func MakeMuxer(prefix string) http.Handler {

log.Println("**** drugs.MakeMuxer(): " + prefix);

var m *mux.Router

// Pass through the prefix if we have one.
if prefix == "" {
    m = mux.NewRouter()
} else {
    m = mux.NewRouter().PathPrefix(prefix).Subrouter()
}


m.HandleFunc("/", CreateDrug).Methods("POST")

// Everything else should 404.
//m.HandleFunc("/{path:.*}", gorca.NotFoundFunc)

return m
}

func CreateDrug(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

log.Println("**** CreateDrug.... ");
log.Println("drugName: " + r.FormValue("drugName"))
//c := appengine.NewContext(r)

}
```

I can see that the POST is getting into "CreateDrug", but `r.FormValue("drugName")` is empty (it is not empty when I use a browser rest plugin and set "drugName" to some value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call [`r.ParseForm()`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.ParseForm) before you can call `r.FormValue`.

//edit

After looking up angularjs, I noticed it sends the data as json, so you have to use [json.NewDecoder](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#NewDecoder), [example](http://play.golang.org/p/oTxWFqqufb):

```
type Drug struct {
    Name string `json:"drugName"`
}
func CreateDrug(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    defer r.Body.Close()
    var d Drug
    dec := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
    dec.Decode(&d)
    log.Println("**** CreateDrug.... ")
    log.Println("drugName:", d.Name)
}
```

Comment: Thx for the help...would you explain a bit "&d" that you used in line "dec.Decode(&d)" ?

Comment: `Decode`, like `Unmarshal`, needs a reference to the object so it could modify it / write to it, so you can either use `&d` to pass a pointer or use `d := new(Drug) // or &Drug{}`.